# Handling exception if error occurs in python

Tags: python, json, for-loop, error-handling, exception

I get an error for few records while I try to parse JSON string, I'm unable to handle the exception such that if an error occurs while parsing JSON string then skip that record and move to next record.

Here is the code snippet.

```
ID=[]
json_string=[]
for row in cursor.fetchall():
 ID.append(row[0]) 
 json_string.append(row[1])
address_fields = {
'intersection': [],        
'political': [],        
'country': [], 
}
dumpData = json.dumps(json_string)
json_all = json.loads(dumpData)

id_index = 0
for json_str in json_all:
     address_fields = {
      'intersection': [],        
      'political': [],        
      'country': [], 
      }
     try:
      json_results = json.loads(json_str)
     except IndexError:
      continue


     if isinstance(json_results,dict):
         first_address_components = json_results['results'][0]['address_components']
     else:
         first_address_components = json_results[0]['address_components']
     for item in first_address_components:
         for field_key in address_fields.keys():
            if field_key in item['types']:
               address_fields[field_key].append(item['long_name'])
```

I first fetch data from sql table and store the take JSON_string and their ID and try to parse JSON string and update those in sql table, so for those JSON string for which I get error, I want to skip that row and move to next record.
But this is not getting done. Still, I m unable to handle exception.
Any help on the same will be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting an exception which stops the program? If so, you need to update the question with the exception trace.

Comment: @quamrana yes , it was a low hanging fruit indeed, the answer below solved my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this

```
try:
  json_results = json.loads(json_str)
except IndexError:
  continue
```

Do this.

```
try:
    json_results = json.loads(json_str)
except:
     pass
```

Comment: Won't these changes try to process an erroneous record instead of skipping it?

Comment: Yes, your answer helped. Thanks!!!. The source data of JSON string itself contains some erroneous string or missing `,` , `;`, or missing `'`

Comment: Having an all catching `except` is very bad style. Be careful with it.